# Use of RTL Languages Causes UI-Disfiguration

Tags: bug, status-completed, display-names, rendering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will there be RTL support in StackExchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5303/will-there-be-rtl-support-in-stackexchange)

Check out my current display name, and Hebrew comments below... (name now changed back, see screen shots below)

http://img.skitch.com/20100320-ka1rg6yf4ws8ums55rdqw71suu.png

http://img.skitch.com/20100320-byi4gx35tpad4g3we4c5dj5k8k.png

Also see [the comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42982/use-of-rtl-languages-causes-ui-disfiguration/42987#42987) on Atwood's response for an example of mixed LTR/RTL comments. (screenshot below)

http://img.skitch.com/20100320-t9eq2esr3j6xkiib3fwua8cb7i.png

Comment: I'm in your timestamps, splitting your chars.

Comment: The blood-dimmed tide is loosed, and everywhere the ceremony of innocence is drowned...

Comment: interesting... is that bug caused by some weird right-to-left unicode behavior?

Comment: -1: If this was asked by a low-rep chinese noob member he'd be told to sling his hook. Why not use the language that the site is targeted at, English?

Comment: Kev, you appear to be using Slavic characters in your name...

Comment: Yes very clever, I'm not daft and I know that the characters and glyphs from all our languages historically derive from some deep and rich formative past. However, I think you're smart enough to get my point.

Comment: I take your point but this is meta, it's aimed at an English speaking LTR audience and AFAIK there hasn't been a pro-active attempt to be otherwise. Also see Joel's comment on this answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42373/what-sites-are-currently-missing-from-the-trilogy/42377#42377 which reads to me as, "we're English speaking for now, fit in". If there was a specific localisation issue you had then fine, ask away on SO, but the content and the way it's presented on SO is targeted at a LTR English speaking audience.

Comment: Kev, I think you missed my point. While the discussion will take place in English (as in our conversation right now), RTL languages *may* popup for particular reasons when discussing something along the lines of localization - in which case the UI may become broken, and the users confused. Is it not best that we address is now, here, on Meta?

Comment: Yep ok, I take your point, but quibbling over whether your display name renders or not in Hebrew seems like an edge case. If there was a problem with the markup editor or rendering characters LTR to show an example related to localisation (in a question or answer) then that would be a real issue.

Comment: Kev, I changed the question away from a display-name issue a while back. There's clearly a UI-issue in comments. See the comment I posted on Jeff's response as an example. This leads me to believe there are likely some cases where post-bodies will behave unpredictably as well. **Confirmed:** Hebrew can definitely mess up your post-body, just confirmed it in the sandbox.

Comment: Well I'll agree to disagree on whether it's important or not, but my point still stands, the SO sites UI are primarily aimed at LTR English speaking users (for now). And my point being that if a low-rep RTL language user had raised the issue then it would be pointed out quite clearly the the site is aimed at LTR English speaking users. And tbh, using hebrew as your display especially as a mod on an English speaking site isn't very clever. Took me a moment to work out if you were really Jonathon or not.

Comment: FWIW, no one but moderators can use RTL characters in their name anyway. I tried copying some Hebrew from Jonathan's profile yesterday into my profile name and it was rejected as not being in the proper character range.

Comment: @Ether Did you prefix it with a number or letter? That is why I placed "9" at the beginning of the string. Hebrew alone was rejected.

Comment: @Jonathan, do you need a saucer of milk?

Comment: ‮And here, you see the issue in live...

Answer (score 2):

Probably a RTL issue. Not anything we're explicitly doing..

ah, except we were not allowing anything other than [A-Z0-9] when validating the first character. Fixed.

Now we use `^[\w](?<!_)`

[image]

Comment: English and Hebrew is neat... מערכת שבורה סוסי הפוני מתים

Comment: (Being focussed on that "9" in the user name, which renders differently in the above comment than in other comments, I first didn't see that the Hebrew comment-text is to to the right of the name. A screen capture, assuming Jonathan will one day revert his user name: http://img.skitch.com/20100320-t9eq2esr3j6xkiib3fwua8cb7i.png)