# Badge information text directions reversed after Hebrew RTL name in user signature

Tags: support, bug, status-declined, flair, internationalization

Is the order of rep and badges in the following image a feature or a bug?

[image: Badge information after Hebrew name has directions reversed]

I think it follows the user's right to left preference, but still

Comment: link? to the image?

Comment: @user156316 Link to real image http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640449/is-there-a-standard-way-to-tell-brew-homebrew-package-manager-for-mac-os-to-bui

Comment: Ha! The user has a unicode RTL control character in his display name, obviously. See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49266/initial-non-iso646-character-refused-in-display-name/49273#49273

Comment: @Yi Hmmm seems safer to call it a feature and move on :)

Comment: BTW .. the user's name is _Reuben_ . Thanks Google Translate

Comment: @Yi Jiang Thanks for the edit. The title is much more clear now.

Answer (score 2):

We don't actually support RTL at the moment, so entering it anywhere is strictly "use at your own risk".

Comment: Ok, well behaved RTL is not very important in a site designed primarily to run in English, I guess. Let's say only the second line in the user's signature has some sort of "undefined behavior", just to share the ownership of the risks.